Accessing camera on Chromebook
Recently purchased a chromebook. I'm trying to use openCV in IDLE to access my camera however I am unable to get any video.
Cheese on linux cannot access my camera either.
The built in camera app on the chromebook works fine.
I used this code along with others of similar nature and none could access my camera
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
    exit()

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print("Error: Could not read frame.")
        break

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Camera Feed', frame)

    # Press 'q' to exit the loop
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if "Cheese" can't do it, it's probably a matter of permissions granted at the system level, or Chromebooks aren't a proper GNU+Linux environment and the webcam isn't exposed as a proper V4L2 device, or that "Linux" it presents to you isn't being granted full access to the hardware. that also means it's not an issue specific to OpenCV. so now you'll have to find out how the OS on Chromebooks is different.

https://chromeunboxed.com/camera-access-for-linux-on-chromeos-may-be-very-close/ -- that's a system issue.

Is linux access necessary? sorry if this seems like an obvious question however my goal is to open the camera using IDLE is there some sort of work around where i could use the feed from the camera app or something of that sort?

oh right, well thank you very much for your help
